# How can I use a unique non-administrative theme for the admin role?

Tags: 10

I have an admin role in my website and I want that based on that role, the non-administrative theme would be different than the default one. For example, if the installed and default non-administrative theme for all users is Olivero, then the installed and default non-administrative theme for me as an admin should be something else, for example a contributed theme I have downloaded.

How could I do that?

Comment: Certainly not because I mean only to non-administrative theme. The administrative theme shouldn't change.

Comment: It seems like some of the answers there would apply. In any case, are you asking for modules for us to find or to recommend?

Comment: I didn't set any limitations on anyone (modules or otherwise).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckily, there are a couple of modules that can help you. I've used the [Theme Negotiation by Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/theme_rule) module in several projects to provide functionality similar to your requirements.

> Usage: As a site builder, visit the Appearance page and click the Theme rules tab. Use the Add theme rule action button to add new rules.

Then, you can define conditions, such as the user role, path (patterns), etc., to indicate the alternative theme to use.

Comment: Thanks. I think I can also do this with the module Context. https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/317934/context-condition-by-role-with-reaction-by-theme-causes-website-to-partially-cra