# Context condition by role with reaction by theme causes website to partially crash

Tags: 10

I have setted a [Context](https://www.drupal.org/project/context) **condition** by role (admin) with **reaction** of using a theme different than the default one, and my problem is that it caused my website to partially crash; I as an admin get the following error in all pages:

> An unexpected error occurred. Please try again later

The website **keeps working** for non admin role users (i.e anonymous users, regular registered users, etc.) but I as an admin can't use it.

Flushing all caches with Drush didn't help.

### Watchdog

In the SQL watchdog table I only see a few **"Page not found"** errors without further detailing.

`vendor/bin/drush watchdog:show`

```
------- -------------- ---------------- ---------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ID      Date           Type             Severity   Message
 ------- -------------- ---------------- ---------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  85934   16/Dec 17:21   php              error      Twig\Error\SyntaxError: Unknown "endif" tag. in Twig\Parser->subparse() (line 37 of
                                                     /home/USERNAME/WEB_APPLICATION_ROOT/example.com/web/themes/contrib/basic/templates/layout/html.html.twig).
```

The theme I made the Context reaction about is named [Basic](https://www.drupal.org/project/basic), so this is probably related.

### Things I consider

#### 1. Programatically unset the Context reaction somehow

Putting some PHP like one of these somewhere, but where?

```php
<?php
/**
* Implementation of hook_context_load_alter().
*/
function custom_module_context_load_alter(&$context) {
  if ($context->name == 'context_name') {
    if (arg(0) == "view_path") //on friends view now
    dpm($context->reactions['block']['blocks']); //find your block name
    unset($context->reactions['block']['blocks']['block_name']); //unset block condition
  }
}
?>
```

or:

```php
<?php
function mymodule_update7101() {
 
  $result = db_select('context', 'c')
    ->fields('c')
    ->condition('name', 'machine_name_of_context_to_edit', '=')
    ->execute()
    ->fetchAssoc();
  $conditions = unserialize($result['conditions']);
  $reactions = unserialize($result['reactions']);
  
  unset($reactions['block']['blocks']['block_name_to_remove']);
  unset($conditions['path']['values']['condition_path_url_to_remove']);
  $conditions['path']['values']['condition_path_url_to_set'] = 'condition_path_url_to_set';
  
  db_update('context')
    ->fields([
      'conditions' => serialize($conditions),
      'reactions' => serialize($reactions),
    ])
    ->condition('name', 'machine_name_of_context_to_edit', '=')
    ->execute();
}
?>
```

[Code credits](https://www.drupal.org/project/context/issues/1094804)

#### 2. Merely removing Context module altogether

If simply removing Context module altogether as follows would help, then I don't have any problem whatsoever to do that, but I am just afarid that it would do more harm than good.

```shell
vendor/bin/drush un context
composer remove 'drupal/context:^5.0@RC'
```

So what can be done in that case besides recovering data from a yesterday backup?

Comment: Knowing what exception was logged would go a long way to answering this.

Comment: How could I know what the exception is, in this case?

Comment: Most web apps and other software write logs by default. Normally exception messages are written to those logs.

Comment: I did not deny that. I have added a chapter "Watchdog" to the question.

Comment: The code in `custom_module_context_load_alter()` is for Drupal 7; `mymodule_update7101()` would be an update hook for Drupal 7, when the function name is corrected. They cannot be used in Drupal 10.

Comment: Did you not check the web server’s logs?

Comment: @cilefen in my hosting environment I can't use `/var/log/apache2/error_log` but from Cpanel Raw Data I don't find anything unusual. The pattern is `198.235.24.9 - - [16/Dec/2023:07:31:12 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 707 "-" "-"`.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a known bug in the theme, which only has a alpha release: https://www.drupal.org/project/basic/issues/3366754.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated by `vendor/bin/drush watchdog:show` the problem was in a twig file of the Basic theme because when I have changed in `/themes/contrib/basic/templates/layout/html.html.twig` from this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html{{ html_attributes }}>
{% endif %}
```

to that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html{{ html_attributes }}>
```

I could then finally use my website as an admin and with Basic theme as a non-administrative theme unique to me as an admin.
I then went to `/admin/structure/context` and manually removed the particular condition-reaction discussed here.